# AWS Service Connect With Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Looking for a working terraform plan to configure AWS Service Connect With ECS (FARGATE).

This is what I have:

```
resource "aws_service_discovery_http_namespace" "my-cloudmap-namespace" {
  name        = "<namespace>"
  description = "Namespace for Service Discovery"
}
```

Container Definition:

```
[
    {
        "name": "my-service-container",
        "image": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "cpu": 0,
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [{
            "name": "my-service",
            "containerPort": 4002,
            "hostPort": 4002,
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "appProtocol": "http"
        }]
    }
]
```

Then In the Service Definition:

```
service_connect_configuration {
    enabled = true
    namespace = aws_service_discovery_http_namespace.my-cloudmap-namespace.arn
    service {
      client_alias {
        dns_name = "my-service"
        port = "4002"
      }
      discovery_name = "my-service"
      port_name = "my-service"
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work. I am not able to reach my service on http://my-service:4002/ from another instance.

Has anyone successfully configured Service Connect with ECS (FARGATE) using terraform ?

Comment: I am having the same issue right now and I am working with AWS to find a solution. My hunch is that your discovery service is being registered as "http" rather than a DNS method. So you can't just use the dns name 'my-service', you'd have to call into the discovery API to get a list of available services and ips. If I get a good answer, I'll come back and submit it.

Comment: If it helps, I was able to resolve the issue by changing the "Computer Options" when creating the service. Instead of "Launch Type" if you select "Capacity provider strategy" it works as expected.

Comment: Also make sure that the security group associated with the service has access from itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that you have the roles for executing the proxy API calls. You should also try with a security group allowing everything at start if your work is not critical, so you make sure to not have any lock on that side. Then you could define your security group as you need (because the security group can block on the Proxy part).

You should create the task and service like this:

```
# Your task definition.
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "your_task" {
  family                   = "your_service_family"
  cpu                      = 512
  memory                   = 1024
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_instance_role.arn
  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name      = "your_name"
    image     = "your_image"
    cpu       = 1
    memory    = 1024
    essential = true
    portMappings = [{ containerPort = 8000, hostPort = 8000, name = "my-port" }]
  }])
}

# And your service.
resource "aws_ecs_service" "your_service" {
  cluster         = your_cluster.arn
  name            = "your_service_name"
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.your_task.arn
  ...
  service_connect_configuration {
    enabled   = true
    namespace = aws_service_discovery_http_namespace.service_discovery.arn
    service {
      discovery_name = "service"
      port_name      = "my-port"
      client_alias {
        dns_name = "your-dns"
        port     = 8000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Be careful to have the roles:

```
# Default ECS Task Execution policy defined directly by AWS.
data "aws_iam_policy" "amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy" {
  name = "AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

# Default ECS Task Instance policy defined directly by AWS.
data "aws_iam_policy" "amazon_ec2_container_service_for_ec2_role" {
  name = "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_assume_role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    sid     = ""
    effect  = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com", "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_tasks_secrets_policy" {
  statement {
    resources = ["*"]
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "ssm:GetParameters",
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_tasks_secrets" {
  name        = "ecsTasksSecrets"
  description = "Access Secrets in ECS Tasks"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_tasks_secrets_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  managed_policy_arns = [
    data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy.arn,
    aws_iam_policy.ecs_tasks_secrets.arn,
  ]
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_instance_role" {
  name                = "ecsInstanceRole"
  managed_policy_arns = [data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ec2_container_service_for_ec2_role.arn]
  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_assume_role.json
}
```

Be careful to have the `task_role_arn` on your task, otherwise the proxy can not translate your API call to the IP.

[Some AWS Docs for the Container Instance role.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html)
[Some AWS Docs for Service Connect.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html)
[Some AWS Docs for Task Execution role.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html)